# NVidia`s ISA language

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor, instruction-set

AMD defines for each GPU family ot its ISA.
As I understand, ISA is a instruction set architecture : assembly -like "language".
How is called NVidia`s GPU "assembly -like language"? - PTX?
Is there any tool like  AMD or Intel offline compiler which generates such assembly for NVidia kernels ?
Thanks

Comment: No, PTX is an abstract, platform-independent intermediate language, somewhat similar to, say, LLVM IR.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697842/do-graphic-cards-have-instruction-sets-of-their-own | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341502/what-instruction-set-does-the-nvidia-geforce-6xx-series-use GPUCC by Google, merged into clang, seems to compile to whatever it is that NVIDIA uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVIDIA assembly language is called SASS.  You can generate SASS from a compiled kernel using the `cuobjdump` tool.   If the name of your executable is `foo`, use `cuobjdump -sass foo`   The output is close enough to the type of PTX output you get from doing `nvcc -ptx foo.cu` that you should be able to understand it with the [PTX ISA reference manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf)