# What instruction set does the Nvidia GeForce 6xx Series use?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, instruction-set

Does the GeForce 6xx Series GPUS use RISC, CISC or VLIW style instructions?

In one source, at http://www.motherboardpoint.com/risc-cisc-t241234.html someone said 
*"GPUs are probably closer to VLIW than to RISC or CISC"*.

In another source, at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word#implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word#implementation) it says *"both Nvidia and AMD have since moved to RISC architectures in order to improve performance on non-graphics workload"*

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353136/is-there-an-assembly-language-for-cuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Nvidia does not publicly document it's hardware instruction sets.

The best you can see officially is [PTX ISA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) which is the instruction set of a virtual machine which Nvidia's compiler (or drivers) then convert to the real instruction set to be executed on specific GPU. [cuobjdump](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html) utility can show you disassembled GPU code. IMHO it looks like a fairly typical RISC -- load+store+operations on registers.

On the other hand, some operations are *very* complex. For instance, texture lookup instruction does a lot -- it may interpolate coordinates, deal with coordinates being out of range, fetch required data and convert it to desired data type. While the syntax remains RISC-y, the substance feels like CISC.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did want to see what some instructions looked like, and the [link]http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html page showed them.

Answer (score 1):

They use a combination of VLIW and SIMID, this allows them to complete several processes at once rather than doing them one by one like RISC or CISC.